# Increase EC2 Disk size

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to increase the hard drive size of an EC2 instance.

I found the volume, modified it from 8 to 20GB.

Then I logged in the server (ssh) and run the commands

```
lsblk
sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1
```

Now the two commands show different size for the hard drive..

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxx:~$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0     7:0    0 16.5M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/784
loop1     7:1    0 88.2M  1 loop /snap/core/5897
loop2     7:2    0 87.9M  1 loop /snap/core/5742
loop3     7:3    0 12.7M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/495
loop4     7:4    0   18M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/930
loop5     7:5    0 87.9M  1 loop /snap/core/5328
xvda    202:0    0   20G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   20G  0 part /
ubuntu@ip-xxx:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           798M  768K  797M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  6.9G  873M  89% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       17M   17M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/784
/dev/loop3       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/495
/dev/loop4       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/930
/dev/loop1       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/5897
/dev/loop2       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5742
/dev/loop5       88M   88M     0 100% /snap/core/5328
tmpfs           798M     0  798M   0% /run/user/1000
```

My runcloud.io dashboard also shows that the size did not change (still 8GB).

I also restared the server without any luck.

What should I do?

File system info

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxx:~$ sudo file -s /dev/xvd*
/dev/xvda:  DOS/MBR boot sector
/dev/xvda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=xxxxx, volume name "cloudimg-rootfs" (needs journal recovery) (extents) (64bit) (large files) (huge files)
```

Comment: Please mention which file system you are using ?

Comment: @varnit Added..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1

After running that command you might need to reboot

Answer (score 0):

According to AWS sometimes the ebs volume needs re initializing after resize you can use dd or fio to reinitialize a volume but fio is faster than dd

[reinitializing ebs volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-initialize.html)

Comment: (NB: for boring straight sequential read of a disk `fio` will not be faster than a `dd` that is using the appropriate `direct` flag and a sensibly large block size)